# How do i get the icon and input box right aligned inside my header

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to css and everything i have tried did not really work out for me. All i want is to have my icon and input box right aligned inside my header.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

This is my header html:

```
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <a  routerLink="/cookbook" routerLinkActive="active">Cookbook</a>
  <a  routerLink="/cookbook/create-recipe/-1" routerLinkActive="active">Add Recipe</a>
  <a  routerLink="/cookbook/find-recipe" routerLinkActive="active">Find Recipe</a>
  <mat-icon class="icon" >search</mat-icon>
  <input class="search" matInput placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

How do i get them right aligned without overlapping?

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to achieve what you want.

Do something like this, give different class to the group you want to separate and then use the flex box `nth-child` property.

```css
.toolbar{
  display:flex;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  padding:12px;
}
.first:first-child{
    margin-right :auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <div class="first" >  
  <a  routerLink="/cookbook" routerLinkActive="active">Cookbook</a>
  <a  routerLink="/cookbook/create-recipe/-1" routerLinkActive="active">Add Recipe</a>
  <a  routerLink="/cookbook/find-recipe" routerLinkActive="active">Find Recipe</a>
   </div>
  <div class="second">
  <mat-icon class="icon" >search</mat-icon>
  <input class="search" matInput placeholder="Search">
   </div>
</div>
```